# In R program, lapply returns incorrect output when list includes POSIXct types

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, posixct

I'm writing a function to iterate over the columns in a data frame to build up a list of each by name and by type.  I'm using `lapply` to get the work done.

I have come across a strange problem where if the type of the column is a `POSIXct` then my function is actually repeating each column twice in the output.

Here are the sample data frames.

```
t1 <- data.frame(a = Sys.time(), 
                 b = "1", c=1, d=1.0, 
                 e=factor("one"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

t2 <- data.frame(b = "1", 
                 c=1, d=1.0, e=factor("one"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

t3 <- data.frame(a = Sys.time(), b = Sys.time(), 
                 c = "1", d=1, e=1.0, 
                 f=factor("one"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And the function:

```
listColumns <- function(df, halt = FALSE) {
  ct <- 0
  r <- unlist(lapply(names(df), FUN = function(x) {
    p <- paste0("* ", x[[1]], " (", class(df[[x]]), ")\n");
    ct <- ct + 1
    p
  }))
  stopifnot(!halt | (length(names(df)) == ct))
  r
}
```

if you try `listColumns()` on `t2`, you get the correct output.  If you try it on `t1` or `t3` where one or more types are `POSIXct`, you get double-output for the date/time columns.

What gives?

**Bad output:**

```
> listColumns(t1)
[1] "* a (POSIXct)\n"   "* a (POSIXt)\n"    "* b (character)\n" "* c (numeric)\n"  
[5] "* d (numeric)\n"   "* e (factor)\n"
```

**Correct output:**

```
> listColumns(t2)
[1] "* b (character)\n" "* c (numeric)\n"   "* d (numeric)\n"   "* e (factor)\n"
```

Comment: Look at the output of `class(t1[[1]])`. The class attribute can in general be a vector, not a single value.

Comment: @joran that's it.  `class(df[[x]])[1]` in my code above eliminates the duplication.  Thanks!